# Функция Random.Range() выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = System.Random;

public class MeteorSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject mateorPrefab;
    public float maxSpawnDelay = 3f;
    public float minSpawnDelay = 1f;
 
    public float spawnXLimit = 6f;

    private void Start()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        float random = Random.Range(-spawnXLimit, spawnXLimit);
    }
}
```

Unity выдает ошибку:

> Random does not contain a definition for Range()

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё правильно, вы пытаетесь использовать `Random`  непосредственно от C#, а надо от *Unity*.

Удалите строку `using Random = System.Random;`